# How can I Create a Playlist on my iPod without Apple Music and without iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod, apple-music

So iTunes is gone but I still have iPods and like to create playlists on them. But I can't figure out how without subscribing to Apple Music. You can sync music but it appears only as songs and not playlists. I even specify syncing Playlists but everything still appears as a list of songs with no breakdown into playlists.

Comment: It would be useful to include the version of iOS on your iPod. Also, do you have a Windows device? iTunes is still available on Windows.